# SQL Server : restoring a backup results in "The log in this backup set is too recent"

Tags: sql-server, database, backup

I have a maintenance plan for full and transaction log backup. It takes a full backup every day at 9 PM evening, and takes a log backup the next morning at 8:30 AM.

When I try to restore the morning log backup after restoring the previous evening's full backup (9 pm), it throws an error

> The log in this backup set is too recent

but there is no other backup taken in between those two.

Is there anything I can do?

- SSMS v17.18.1
- SQL Server 2016 (v13.0.1601.5)

Comment: "and Takes a log backup next day morning 8:30 AM" - erm, that sounds like a bad idea...Take log backups frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the backup LSN data from your msdb.

```
select  s.backup_set_id, 
        s.first_lsn,
        s.last_lsn,
        s.database_name,
        s.backup_start_date,
        s.backup_finish_date,
        s.type,
        f.physical_device_name
from    msdb..backupset s join msdb..backupmediafamily f
        on s.media_set_id = f.media_set_id
```

Most likely you are restoring the wrong file / Order.

Comment: Thank you So much, This is what i am looking for.